# Add images to my theme with html

Tags: images

I've uploaded an image to my directory (themes/themename/images/file.png).  I want this image to be displayed even if the directory preceding themes is changed (in case someone installs wordpress in a directory other than the home directory).

What is the call I need to find the image?  Simply using img src="/images/file.png" does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/file.png" />
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo